# How to retrieve data from firebase asynchronously in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I just try to retrieve data from firebase in a constructor with following code and return value of that object is undefined when page load. But it is working fine in a click event. How to fix this issue?

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('news');
    $scope.newslist = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the data change is not being registered by AngularJS. Try calling `$scope.$applyAsync();` after `$scope.newslist = $firebaseArray(ref);`.